# Nifi - Separate the column in two colums (Array)

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON :

```json
{
  "consultor_do_projeto": [
    "Iago de Oliveira",
    "Murilo Tavares"
  ]
}
```

I need to transform in:

```json
{
  "consultor0" : "Iago de Oliveira",
  "consultor1" : "Murilo Tavares"
}
```

In Jolt Spec, Can I do this?

if the third item exists, it will be the `consultor2`

Thanks to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do through use of a Jolt spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*_do_projeto": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&(2,1)&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **&(2,1)** brings the **1**st asterisk replacement from the **2** levels up (eg. the substring "consultor")

*and*

- **&** next to that brings the counterpart value for **@** sign which refers the indexes (**`0,1,..`**) of the array.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]